# Poly/ML Exception Cast "toAddress" raised

Tags: sml, polyml

Using Poly/ML, I wanted to write a function to construct an n*n identity matrix using Array of Arrays.

I wrote:

```
fun equiv x y = if x = y then 1 else 0;
fun idmatrix n = Array.tabulate(n, fn i => (Array.tabulate(n, equiv i)));
```

and it compiled successfully, giving

```
> val equiv = fn: ''a -> ''a -> int
> val idmatrix = fn: int -> int array array
```

But when I called *idmatrix*

```
idmatrix 2;
```

for a test, the output of the compiler was

```
> Exception- Cast "toAddress" raised
```

Can anybody explain why the exception was raised, please?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works fine for me. Looking at [the code that raises the exception](https://searchcode.com/codesearch/view/21723258/#l-120), perhaps it's a 32/64-bit address problem? Is your Poly/ML compiled for the right architecture?

Poly/ML:

```
$ poly
Poly/ML 5.2 Release
> fun equiv x y = if x = y then 1 else 0;
val equiv = fn : ''a -> ''a -> int
> fun idmatrix n = Array.tabulate(n, fn i => (Array.tabulate(n, equiv i)));
val idmatrix = fn : int -> int Array.array Array.array
> idmatrix 3;
val it = fromList[fromList[1, 0, 0], fromList[0, 1, 0], fromList[0, 0, 1]]
: int Array.array Array.array
```

Moscow ML:

```
$ mosml
Moscow ML version 2.10
Enter `quit();' to quit.
- fun equiv x y = if x = y then 1 else 0;
> val ''a equiv = fn : ''a -> ''a -> int
- fun idmatrix n = Array.tabulate(n, fn i => (Array.tabulate(n, equiv i)));
> val idmatrix = fn : int -> int array array
- idmatrix 3;
> val it = <array> : int array array
```

And SML/NJ:

```
$ sml
Standard ML of New Jersey v110.76 [built: Sun Jun 29 03:29:51 2014]
- fun equiv x y = if x = y then 1 else 0;
stdIn:1.23 Warning: calling polyEqual
val equiv = fn : ''a -> ''a -> int
- fun idmatrix n = Array.tabulate(n, fn i => (Array.tabulate(n, equiv i)));
[autoloading]
[library $SMLNJ-BASIS/basis.cm is stable]
[autoloading done]
val idmatrix = fn : int -> int array array
- idmatrix 3;
val it = [|[|1,0,0|],[|0,1,0|],[|0,0,1|]|] : int array array
```

Comment: Ahh, I restarted my Poly/ML and it worked. I then realised that in the previous session I set "trace" to true in PolyML.Debug tools and forgot to turn that off. I guess that when the compiler was tracing the function, something bad happened (ran out of memory?) But THANK YOU very much for testing them patiently :)